# QNAP TS-419p Volume Full, now cannot delete files to free up space

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, files

I have a QNAP TS-419p. It is set up with 4x 1TB disks in RAID 6.

There is only 10MB of space left on the volume. When I try to delete files from the server, I cannot. From the web interface, I get network timeout error. From SSH issuing the rm command just locks up and emptying the network recycle bin from the admin console just hangs on 'Applying'

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the firmware that was out of date needed updating. Doesn't really explain why the problem existed to begin with. But here are instructions as supplied by QNAP tech support:

1. Power of the NAS
2. Remove all the HDDs
3. Power on the NAS
4. After a short beep and a long beep(about two minutes after first short beep), run the QNAP Finder(Make sure the Finder is the latest version).
5. QNAP Finder should find the NAS and its IP
6. Select the NAS and click “Tools” -> “Update Firmware”
7. Input default username and password (admin/admin)
8. Follow the page to select the firmware file ( the flash image file which is about 13MB to 14MB).
   http://us1.qnap.com/Storage/tsd/flashimage/TS-419P_20101217-3.3.8.Flash.img
9. After firmware update, the NAS will be reboot.
10. Make sure the firmware have been updated
11. Power off the NAS
12. Plug all the HDD back
13. After power on, Update the firmware again using the update image on QNAP download site( which is about 90MB to 100MB).